# php change database with sub domain

Tags: php, mysql

I searched in google, stackoverflow but all topics related `php` framework not core `php`, I want to know what is the best solution to change database depend on sub domain. i have a multi language website, i want to use single source code but with different sub domain, just change db according to sub domain name.

**Here is my code:**

```
$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$sub = array_shift((explode('.', $domain)));
if ($sub == 'tr') {
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "db_tr";
  $password = "xxxxx";
  $dbname = "xxxx";
} else if ($sub == 'gb') {
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "db_gb";
  $password = "xxxxx";
  $dbname = "xxxx";
} else if ($sub == 'us') {
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "db_us";
  $password = "xxxxx";
  $dbname = "xxxx";
} else if ($sub == 'ca') {
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "db_ca";
  $password = "xxxxx";
  $dbname = "xxxx";
} else {
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "db_all";
  $password = "xxxxx";
  $dbname = "xxxx";
}
```

**So i have two question:**

1. Is this logic good in programming? if not, What is the best solution to do this?
2. Is it harmful? for example for `sql` injection, hack or other security issue.

Comment: in almost every case it's a bad idea to use different databases just because the language switch. if the project is not trivial or if it will grow this will become unmaintable

Comment: The matter is, this website designed for about five top country, i don't want to use a single database , I estimate it will be big data, then second problem is if i change something, need to modify all 5 website. so if it's bad idea, what is the best solution? @snap

Comment: a database is for big data. you should only have one app with one database and some multilanguage support in it. so basically you will have one table where you have multiple rows for the same text element with values for different locations. maybe you can take advance of a framework or lib here.

Comment: I know there is a solution in Laravel and etc.. but unfortunately site done with php core. you right, big data not important matter. but the modify../ it's not the language issue, the products are different than other country.  for example, in one website will show `us` products, another `england` and.. @snap But if it's bad, i have to change my mind and use single app with single db. but wondering how can i separate each country data depend on sub domain.

Comment: ok i sayed in almost every case, i dont know all your requirements and maybe multiple db are a fit for you. you should just think twice before you should a path here